# How to find out that string contain unicode character in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I came across situation where i want to check that given string contain unicode character or not?How to do that?

Comment: Every string in C# consists of Unicode characters, please clarify your question.

Comment: I mean to say non english character.Regional language....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
string input = ... // your input.

if(input.Any(c => c > 255))
{
    // unicode 
}
```

Comment: Do you care to elaborate what "something like this" does exactly, and how that solves the OP's problem?